# How to import table from a lua file to another lua file in Neovim?

Tags: lua, neovim

I want to import a table from a lua file (`custom_header.lua`) containing ascii art to use as custom headers in dashboard-nvim plugin. In `init.lua` file I have this following code:

```lua
local db = require('dashboard')
local header_import = require('custom_header')
local imported_header_list = header_import.custom_header_list()
db.custom_header = imported_header_list[1]
```

In `custom_header.lua` file:

```lua
logo_list = {}
function logo_list.custom_header_list()
  header_choose = 
  {
     {
      '.................',
      '..... Art 1 ...',
     },
    {
     '.............',
      '...art 2 ...',
    }
  }
  return header_choose
end
return logo_list
```

Both files are in same directory. But when I'm opening neovim it's throwing me error saying:

> module 'custom_header' not found

Folder structure is following:

`.config/nvim/lua/dash-config/(init.lua, custom_header.lua)`

All the other lua files are sourced at a `init.lua` file that is in the lua folder.

What I'm doing wrong here ?

Comment: What directory are they in? How are you running your init.lua?

Comment: .config/nvim/lua/dash-config/(init.lua, custom_header.lua)  In lua folder there is the main init.lua file. On that file every other lua file is sourced including the init.lua that is in dash-config folder. When I open neovim those files are sourced by neovim automatically.  @Jasmijn

Comment: Make sure your execution is where you thing it is, it often is the executable running the file not the file's location. If your not in the expected folder you can add paths to your `package.path` variable to resolve the requires properly

Comment: It seems like a path issue for require funciton, it can not find your module. BTW, it is always better to edit your post and add the missing info, so that people can better help you, for free :)

Comment: Thank you for the tip sir. I'll keep that in mind from now on. @jdhao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how neovim configures Lua, you should be able to require subpackages like so:

```
local header_import = require('dash-config.custom_header')
```

or like so:

```
local header_import = require('dash-config/custom_header')
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, c'mon, what could be more straightforward than this?!

```lua
-- custom_header.lua
return {
    { --1
    },

    { --2
    },

    -- even more
}
```

```lua
-- main
require"dashboard".custom_header = require"dash-config.custom_header"[1]
```

> Both files are in same directory. But when I'm opening neovim it's throwing me error saying --> module 'custom_header' not found
> What I'm doing wrong here ?

Lua files must be under `lua` subdirectory of `&runtimepath`.

Comment: Thank you sir. Custom header file was in lua/dash-config folder. Not doing require("dash-config.custom_header") was throwing the error. So what do I do when I want to import a file that is not under lua subdirectory ?

Comment: @MimicMannan If it's in lua/foobar then it's **under** lua  but the prefix (i.e. foobar) must be always specified. And if it's not under lua then you have to tweak package.path first.